# How can I catch JS exceptions from async functions I don't control?

Tags: javascript, exception, google-chrome-extension

I know using `try..catch` for async functions doesn't work, and most advice I've read suggests using it inside the passed callback.

However, without control over the async function which throws the exception, what can one do to catch it? In my example it's `chrome.bookmarks.create`, which fails on some edge cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome extensions, there are two possible ways of catching asynchronous errors:

- Listen to global error events using [`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onerror).
- In the callback of asynchronous functions, check the value of [`chrome.runtime.lastError`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-lastError).

Comment: Bummer, all those still won't catch the errors I encountered (around the chrome.bookmarks api). But thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general cases there's no way to catch exceptions on third party functions, you'll have to use error handling methods provided by someone else.

In case of Chrome's extension API you have the [lastError](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#property-lastError) property. Enjoy.